# Error with userid?

Tags: php, localhost, userid

What is wrong here..

```
<?php if($user->getSession()){
                echo '<li><a href="index.php?page=25&id=<?php echo $user[id]; ?>">My Profile</a></li>';
            }else{
                echo '<li><a class="button" href="#prvi">Join Us</a></li>';                 
            } ?>
```

The result of this:

```
index.php?page=25&id=<?php%20echo%20$user[id];%20?>
```

Comment: `echo '<li><a href="index.php?page=25&id=<?php echo $user[id]; ?>">My Profile</a></li>';` - the stuff between the single quotes is called a string literal. In single-quoted string literals php doesn't substitute variables , and it certainly doesn't "look for" other php script blocks - it's just a string literal and echo prints it (more or less) as-is.see http://docs.php.net/language.types.string

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code accordingly :

```
if($user->getSession()){
                echo '<li><a href="index.php?page=25&id='.$user[id].'">My Profile</a></li>';
            }else{
                echo '<li><a class="button" href="#prvi">Join Us</a></li>';                 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

**This**

```
<?php
if($user->getSession()){
    echo '<li><a href="index.php?page=25&id=<?php echo $user[id]; ?>">My Profile</a></li>';
}else{
    echo '<li><a class="button" href="#prvi">Join Us</a></li>';                 
}
?>
```

**Into this**

```
<?php
if($user->getSession()){
    echo '<li><a href="index.php?page=25&id='.$user[id].'">My Profile</a></li>';
}else{
    echo '<li><a class="button" href="#prvi">Join Us</a></li>';                 
}
?>
```

PHP tag is not necessary inline of echo, that is your error.

**Update**

The `$user` variable is a [object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) but used as an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

In you code, change

```
echo '<li><a href="index.php?page=25&id='.$user[id].'">My Profile</a>
```

to this

```
echo '<li><a href="index.php?page=25&id='.$user->id.'">My Profile</a>
```

In object you have to refer to its key with `->` as in arrays you do `[]`

Comment: Thank you but not works, with this I have empty page...(?)

Comment: please include `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of the PHP script and reload the page. Any errors?

Comment: This error  ?: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type LoginRegistration as array in C:\wamp\www\proba\modules\profile_user.php on line 75 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0010251120{main}( )..\index.php:0 20.0190361888include

Comment: And the file it is referring too, on line 75, what exactly is there? Please paste with surrounding code so i can have a better understanding.

Comment: did this answer help Bojan?